# How can i close this modal after the data is successfully inserted? and the page should not be redirected to another page

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, servlets, bootstrap-modal

[image]Index.jsp

> JavaScript :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function myfunction()
            {
                var frm=$("#form1");
                frm.submit(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                       type: frm.attr('method'),
                       url:frm.attr('action'),
                       data: frm.serialize(),
                       success: function(){
                               $('#staticBackdrop').modal('toggle');
                               $('#successalert').show();
                       }  
                    });
               
                });
            };
        </script>
```

staticBackdrop is the modal id and successalert is the alert id which is currently hidden and after success i want to show it.

Index.jsp

Form code which is inside Modal. the id of modal is `staticBackdrop`:-

```
<form action="Home"  name="form1" id="form1" >
    <div class="form-group">

             <input type="text" class="form-control" required="true" id="sub_name" name="sub_name" >

             <input type="text" class="form-control" required="true" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" name="subemail" id="subemail">

                  <input type="text" pattern="^[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$" max="10" class="form-control"  name="sub_number" id="sub_number">

             <button type="submit" onclick="myfunction()" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>             
    </div>
</form>
```

In modal i have textbox to get user `name, email, number`. when user `click on submit button` the above `ajax class` should send that data to `Home Controller` :-

`Home Controller`

```
@WebServlet(name="Home", urlPatterns={"/Home"})
public class Home extends HttpServlet {   
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
     Subcribe s=new Subcribe();
        s.email=request.getParameter("subemail");
        s.name=request.getParameter("sub_name");
        s.number= request.getParameter("sub_number");
        subcribeinsert(s);  //this method will insert into database 
    } 
}
```

But whenever i click on submit button the data is successfully inserted into database but the page get redirected to blank page `url contains all data i was sending via ajax` what is the error?
The Url is

> http://localhost:8080/Jinal/Home?sub_name=example&subemail=emaple%40emaple.com&sub_number=9988776655

The page is blank. I just want to close modal and remain on the page it was earlier

Comment: you need to submit data via ajax ? then why you have `frm.submit(function(){..` ? under your function. Also use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent default submission of form.

Comment: @Swati can you please tell how?

Comment: check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/5k2bLptd/3/) fiddle to understand changes you need to make.

Answer (score 0):

Your page is redirecting because in the form you have mentioned action='home'. Just remove that, you don't need that if you don't want any redirection.

> <form    <strike>action="Home"</strike>    name="form1" id="form1" >

**Edited :**

Also change button type to "button" and remove extra material from JavaScript. As you are already using function, there is no need to use call submit function manually.

**Edited 2:**

Not able to see how you are making changes and the complete files, it is difficult to see why the solutions are not working. That is why I am attaching code snippet, test it and see if it works without redirecting and gives a "Yes" message in console. Then modify it according to your code. I have commented code for "Modal" in success function as I don't have any modal.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>abc</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
      <form name="form1" id="form1" >
        <div class="form-group">
    
                <input type="text" class="form-control" required="true" id="sub_name" name="sub_name" >
    
                <button type="button" onclick="myfunction()" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>             
        </div>
    </form>


    <script type="text/javascript">
      function myfunction()
      {
          var frm=$("#form1");
          $.ajax({
              type: frm.attr('method'),
              url:frm.attr('Home.html'),
              data: frm.serialize(),
              success: function(){                
                      //$('#staticBackdrop').modal('toggle');
                      //$('#successalert').show();
                      console.log("Yes")
              }  
          });
      }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @RishabhJain I have edited the answer, check it out. Hope it is fixed now.

Comment: i tried this also. this is also not working. can you suggest anything else?

Comment: @RishabhJain The page is redirecting? Or is it another kind of error. Would be better if you could show image of  "Inspect element". It will show errors if there are some.

Comment: @RishabhJain Check my Post again, I have edited it.